# How to edit a object property that is inside on an userContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I change a property inside a useContext?

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();
const { obra, setObra } = useContext(AuthContext);
setObra(...obra, ...obra.nome_equipe_01 = e.target.value);
```

I Want to change the property 'nome_equipe_01' inside the 'obra' object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the intended key, for example:

```
setObra(prevState => ({...prevState, nome_equipe_01: e.target.value }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setObra({...obra,nome_equipe_01: "value"})
```

or you can create a specific function that update specific prop on the context

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).